# How is the DOM represented when one script is used for multiple static pages?

Tags: javascript, html

My thoughts are it's represented normally with multiple pages. For example if I have three pages, all using one script lets say javascript.js . If I use my one script to try and located a `<div>` for example using `document.getElementsByTagName('div')`. Will a node list contain a reference to each div on each page? Or will it just use one page?

Comment: It will just use one page (the current page) because `document` only refers to the current page.

Comment: a script always runs in the current page. It doesn't know anything about the other pages.